# Connect google data studio to google cloud sql

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, looker-studio

I'm trying to connect Google Data Studio to a MySQL first-generation instance in Google Cloud SQL.

Error message:

Access denied, please check your username and password.

Error ID: 4db6a388

I've tried to use  Google Cloud SQL connector,  tried MySQL connector. Both tried also via JDBC. No success. With MySQL connector I've tried to add list of Data Studio IP's

In Google Cloud SQL connector manual I've found:

A Data Studio data source can connect to a single Cloud SQL database table.
You must have at least cloudsql.client permission in the Cloud SQL project to create the connection. If you don't have this access, you can use the MySQL connector instead.

Should I use IAM to grant cloudsql.client permission? How should I specify Data Studio in New member textbox? I've tried to specify my user, but this also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely typing in the instance connection name wrong. You can copy it from your Cloud SQL instance homepage. The instance connection name should be,
project name:sql server region:instance name